# Element is not horizontally centered in IE11 with Flexbox when parent has flex-flow: column wrap;

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, flexbox

### JSFiddle Link

```css
.thing {
 background-color: tomato;
 max-width: 300px;
 padding: 30px;
 display: flex;
 margin: 0 auto;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.not-centered {
 max-width: 150px;
 background-color: #fefefe;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing">
 <div class="not-centered">
  im not centeredi in ie11
 </div>
</div>
```

I supposed it to work because if `max-width` and `margin: 0 auto` set. But as you can see, it is not horizontally centered because his parent `.thing` has `flex-flow: column wrap`.

Any ideas to fix this in this setup?

*P.S.* Works in Chrome/FF

Comment: Ok whatever. I just wrapped it in a ``div`` and it worked. Jesus IE11's implementaion of Flexbox is a pure garbage =/

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it so that future readers of this question can benefit!

Comment: It should center in IE11 if you just take off `flex-flow: column wrap;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrapping `.not-centered` in a `div` with `block` display resolves the issue in IE11